# How to SUM for Item1 and Item1 + 'char'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about a little SQL problem.

For instance, I have a table **Table** like this:

```
|  ITEM  |  VALUE  |
|A0001   |   3     |
|A0001   |   2     |
|A0002   |   2     |
|A0003   |   7     |
|A0003   |   3     |
|A0003U  |   2     |
```

As you can see, an Item can have may Values. So what I have already done, is to `SUM()` all value attached to each Item, to obtain his **SUM of Value**.

What I want to do now, is adding the values that are attached to an Item and and this Item + 'U'

For example, the **SUM of Value** for the Item **A0003U** will be

7 (line 1 of item) + 3 (line 2 of item) + **2 (line 1 of item + 'U')** = 12

I know that I can use the function RIGHT(Item, 1) that will return 'U' if it endswith a 'U', but I don't know how to make all the calculation.

EDIT:

A resulset should be:

```
|  ITEM  |  VALUE  |
|A0001   |   5     |
|A0002   |   2     |
|A0003   |   12     |
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your desired result set?

Comment: Are they going to be fixed width?  Could you have a A00010 A00010U?

Comment: No, they don't necessary have the same width, here is the problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I over-thought the problem before OP added the expected result-set. Nevertheless here is the query if desired output would be something like:

```
|  ITEM  |  VALUE  |
|A0001   |   5     |
|A0002   |   2     |
|A0003   |   10    |
|A0003U  |   12    |
```

It might turn out to be useful:

```
SELECT 
   a.ITem
   ,CASE 
      WHEN RIGHT(a.ITEM,1)='U' 
        THEN SUM(b.VALUE) 
        ELSE SUM(a.VALUE) 
      END AS VALUE
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b 
  ON a.ITEM = b.ITEM + 'U' 
  OR (RIGHT(a.ITEM,1)='U' AND a.ITEM = b.ITEM)
GROUP BY a.ITem
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e5cf/2)**

**EDIT:**

Query for simplified (actual) version of problem:

```
Select 
  CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(ITEM,1) = 'U' THEN SUBSTRING(ITEM,0,LEN(ITEM)) 
    ELSE ITEM 
  END AS ITEM
  ,SUM(VALUE) as VALUE
From Table1
GROUP BY 
   CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(ITEM,1) = 'U' THEN SUBSTRING(ITEM,0,LEN(ITEM)) 
    ELSE ITEM 
   END
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e5cf/5)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that after working a little on this I will be able to obtain the resultset I expect.

Answer (score 6):

This will sum up the values by taking the first 5 characters of the ITEM column and grouping by them. This will include items that end in `U`

```
Select Left(ITEM,5),
        SUM(VALUE)
From Table
Group by Left(ITEM,5)
```

EDIT

Assuming that `U` is always the last character and only appears once then you can use this alternative:

```
Select  Case 
            When CHARINDEX('U', ITEM) > 0 Then LEFT(ITEM, CHARINDEX('U', ITEM)-1)
            Else ITEM
        End,
        SUM(VALUE)
From Table
Group by    Case 
            When CHARINDEX('U', ITEM) > 0 Then LEFT(ITEM, CHARINDEX('U', ITEM)-1)
            Else ITEM
            End
```

Comment: Oh it sounds great.  But, in fact all Items don't have the same (char)Length, it was an exemple.  For instance I can have an Item named **12345** and an item named *12345678**, but both can have a "U-double".

Comment: @lour Is the `U` always at the end? And always one character?

Comment: Yes, the U is always at the end, but the item name can contain others character.  Like "RN0005", or "RN006PU".